# using durable & autodelete params equally causes error in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

When I am using rabbitmq, when I set durable and autodelete to true, I get this error below,

> Error: Exception (406) Reason: "PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg
> 'auto_delete' for exchange 'logs_topic' in vhost '/': received 'true'
> but current is 'false'"

When I change one of them to false, everything works fine. Why can't I use them both together? In first shot, when I run docker-compose it was working together but when I restart I had to set one of them to false.

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message you shared is for the exchange declaration, so my guess is that your exchange is already declared, was done without the "auto delete" option at first.
As you declare it again, the parameters you provide now include "auto delete", which do not match the existing exchange.